# iOS - Can anyone suggest me how can I integrate gmail account into my app and get the list of all emails?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, search, ios5, gmail

I am developing an App which has a search functionality for user's emails with Gmail Account, But I don't know exactly how to integrate Gmail account into my app and get the list of all emails. And Please let me know if any Search API is available of Gmail for iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look into this website because there is no API from Google to get you're emails. You need to do this through the POP protocol.

http://www.example-code.com/objc/pop3_gmail.asp

then see the features here for the library
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-features.asp

and download the library here
http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_objc.asp

Hope this will get you started with reading emails and listing them, good luck!

as and addition have a look into:
https://github.com/mronge/mailcore

and another addition:
http://www.etpan.org/

Interesting too:
http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/

Comment: And probably the searching you have to do yourself when you have the emails

Comment: Thank you very much QVDev. But can you tell me how can i integrate Gmail to my app for Login and all?

Comment: Which of the resources are you using above? if you use mailcore see the following documentation it uses imap

http://libmailcore.com/gettingstarted.html

Comment: I am using this :http://www.example-code.com/objc/pop3_gmail.asp
but i am not able to compile my build due to this Error : 
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CkoMailMan", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation). I already added classes by **"Add Files to.."** option.

Comment: Make sure you have the compiling target setting etc.. set to the right  architecture

Comment: Yes,It set to the Standard Architecture **armv7** and Base SDK to **iOS5**.I dont know if any other settings are needed?

Comment: I think my compiler cant compile **CkoMailMan.h**. Thats why it is throwing error like this and if i am not wrong **.m** file for **CkoMailMan.h** is needed.Please Help me out of this situation.Please tell me if i am mistaken for adding library to my App.I added **include** folder from **Chilkat-9.3.1-IOS-4.3** folder.