# Integration of gmail with an ios app

Tags: ios, gmail

I am working on an ios app, recently I have gotten a new requirement for it i.e. to make the users able to get the starred emails of their gmail accounts in the app. I don't know how to start, have searched a lot but I haven't gotten any valuable stuff related to this functionality yet.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11428077/1704346)

Comment: Have you went through this link ???? https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps